# vhost support on Bluemix - CloudAMQP

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudamqp

Is it possible to create vhosts for cloudAMQP hosted on IBM Bluemix? If it is possible, which plans would support this?

Our product will make use of CloudAMQP on Bluemix. It has to support multiple tenants. Do we have the option to have one vhost per tenant?

Thank you

Dominic Roy

Answer (score 0):

You are able to create your own vhosts on all dedicated plans, Big Bunny and larger. (A shared plan will only give you one single vhost.)